# Method Enum isBigger()

Tags: java, methods, enums

I am trying to write a method in a Java enum: `isBigger(Valoration val)`, which returns true if if the current rating is bigger than one that is passed as parameter throwing the exception ValorationNoValued if the valuations
compared (or both) is NO_VALUED.

```
public enum Valoracion {
    NO_VALUED(0),
    SO_BAD(0),
    BAD(2),
    OK(4),
    GOOD(6),
    EXCELENT(8),
    WOW(10);

    ....

    public boolean isBigger(Valoration val) throws ValorationNoValued {
        if (val == NO_VALUED) { 
            throw new ValorationNoValued("message");
        }
        else {
            return val.getValor() > this.valor;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if the current rating is NO_VALUED, but I don't know how.

Comment: `this == NO_VALUED`.

Comment: P.S. please **always** use curly brackets for `if..else`. And format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always refer the the “current object” via `this` be it an `enum` or not. But…

It seems, your `enum` has a method `getValor()` to return the numerical value. Then it would be much cleaner to intercept the exceptional state *there* rather than in the comparison method:

```
public enum Valoracion {
    NO_VALUED (0) {
        @Override int getValor() {
            throw new ValorationNoValued("message");
        }
    },
    SO_BAD (0),
    BAD(2),
    OK (4),
    GOOD (6),
    EXCELENT (8),
    WOW (10);

....
int getValor() {
    return valorValue;
}
public boolean isBigger(Valoration val) throws ValorationNoValued {
    return val.getValor()>this.getValor();
}
```

This way, no conditionals are needed and the symmetry between `a.isBigger(b)` and `b.isBigger(a)` comes for free.

If you prefer conditionals over overriding the method, you may still implement the `getValor()` method as

```
int getValor() {
    if(this==NO_VALUED) throw new ValorationNoValued("message");
    return valorValue;
}
```

without the need to care for two sides in the `isBigger` method.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `this`:

```
If (this == NO_VALUED) {
```